# How to generate a range of dates in MariaDB?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I want to insert the date and day of the week for the whole of 2019-01-01 to 2019-12-31. but I`m unable to.

I try date_format function.

[image]

This is my table. table name is food_user and I want to insert the date and day in re_date, re_day 2019-01-01~2019-12-31

[image]

```
INSERT INTO food_user (NAME,re_date,re_day) VALUES ('Alex' , ? , ?);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using MariaDB, try this code to get all dates in year:

```
SELECT '2019-01-01' + INTERVAL seq DAY FROM seq_0_to_364;

or 

SELECT '2018-12-31' + INTERVAL seq DAY FROM seq_1_to_365;
```

To undestand this, MariaDB has a built in SEQUENCE Engine - reference: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/sequence-storage-engine/ .

Basically typing `SELECT seq FROM seq_1_to_10;` will return you a number seq from 1 to 10. In this case, a whole year is 365 days hence seq_1_to_365 will return number from 1 to 365. IF you're counting from zero (0), then you'll need to consider the last value as 364, hence changing the sequence to seq_0_to_364 as the example above. From your query, you can do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO food_user (NAME,re_date,re_day)
SELECT 'Alex','2019-01-01' + INTERVAL seq DAY,DAYNAME('2019-01-01' + INTERVAL seq DAY) FROM seq_0_to_364;
```

**Here's an update**, a few months ago I've discovered a way of using recursive statement to generate date ranges. The `sequence engine` is quite useful but it's only specific to MariaDB. `WITH RECURSIVE` is supported on both MySQL & MariaDB, although it's also version specific; [MySQL from version 8](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html) & [MariaDB from version 10.2.2](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/with/). This is the query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE date_ranges AS (
SELECT '2019-01-01' dt UNION ALL
SELECT dt + INTERVAL 1 DAY FROM date_ranges 
WHERE dt + INTERVAL 1 DAY <= '2019-12-31')

SELECT dt FROM date_ranges;
```

Other than the reason above there's a simple yet important reason why I include this option; it's because of leap years. We had one in 2020 so the total days in that year is actually 366 days instead of 365 days.

[Here is a fiddle showing the difference using sequence engine and with recursive.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=cfdeb8081c88fc15c012a3cfe768bebf)

As you can see in the fiddle, the sequence engine query (for leap year) still return 365 rows and the last date of the year is `2020-12-30`.. we're missing a day. That is caused by the numbering sequence constraint that we've defined (`seq_1_to_365`). Therefore, it might not be the best option to use sequence engine unless you're only using it on non-leap years..

Here is the complete query for the `INSERT` operation according to the question:

```
INSERT INTO food_user(NAME,re_date,re_day)
/*recursive statement here*/
  WITH RECURSIVE date_ranges AS (
   SELECT '2019-01-01' dt UNION ALL
   SELECT dt + INTERVAL 1 DAY FROM date_ranges 
   WHERE dt + INTERVAL 1 DAY <= '2019-12-31')
/*select statement here*/
SELECT 'Alex',dt, dayname(dt) FROM date_ranges;
```

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=45982acf9dd134b579a4c775acf03c6d)

Answer (score 0):

If you use MySQL,
You can try
`insert into food_user(name, re_date, re_day) values("Hello", "2019-01-01", dayofweek("2019-01-01"));`

If you want to insert all days from 2019-01-01 to 2019-12-31, you can use php or any other server side language to insert records.

If you are using Oracle, you can use PL/SQL feature to insert all of them

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can help

```
insert into food_user (name,re_date,re_day) values ('Alex' , DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), "%Y-%m-%d") , DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), "%W"));
```

from https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp